# Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'soap' when parsing MSXML soap response using selectSingleNode

Tags: javascript, xml, soap, msxml

I have an msxml document that I'm trying to parse.

This is the xml -

xmlDoc.responseDocument:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <soap:Body>
        <Response xmlns="http://company.com/Services">
            <Result>test</Result>
        </Response>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

xmlDoc.selectSingleNode("soap:Body") returns "Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'soap'."

Thanks for any help provided.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested, this worked for me -

```
var soapNS = 'xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"';
xmlDoc.documentElement.setProperty("SelectionNamespaces", soapNS);
xmlDoc.document.selectSingleNode("soap:Body");
```